# Spring data mongo conversion is not working for Object type since version 3.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

We have upgraded the Spring Data Mongo recently and since then some read and update queries are failing with the following error,

org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Expected to read Document Document{} into type class java.lang.Object but didn't find a PersistentEntity for the latter!

While debugging, found that the type is Object and it doesn't have _class then this error is thrown.

It was working fine before 3.2.

When checked in the 3.1's source code, the read method in class [MappingMongoConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/3.1.x/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.java#L299) has a logic to cast the bson to an Object type if the ClassTypeInfomartion is Object.

In a few of our object models, we store additional information about the document as an Object.

Is it possible to configure in Spring to convert the bson to Object instead of failing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What object instance type do you expect when the `_class` hint isn't present and the requested object type is `Object.class`?

Comment: I expect to return the Object type. Our code is like this,
class Preference {
private String user;
private String page;
private Object props;
}

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Mongo can take the type information from `_class`, but if the application cannot rely on that field, it needs to tell the driver what type the data it expects to get.

My current project uses this for that purpose:

```
public interface BusinessesRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeApplicationType, String>
```

(Spring Data will autogenerate a subclass with the proper class selection logic for such an interface.)

Slightly lower-level you have `MongoTemplate` with its `find(Query, Class<T>)` function, which accepts something like `SomeApplicationType.class` as the second parameter and uses that information to instantiate an object to populate the fields with.

I don't know what function your code calls to retrieve and deserialize your data, so I can't be more specific.